meltano handling of encoding
I am currently pulling my hair out trying to get meltano to correctly write my data to a target.
Step 1:
The data is extracted correctly using tap-mssql (database has collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS), meltano displays the records in the console, eg:
Message: { ....., Text: "Ему подушки поправлять, \\nПечально подносить лекарство", Text2: "मेरे चाचा सबसे ईमानदार नियम" ...}

So far so good, python correctly handles the UTF8? data.
Step 2:
When meltano tries to write it to target (eg. target-jsonl, target-csv, any...) the problems start.
I really tried every conversion possible, but i cannot fix it.
# tried combining all different encodings
str(record['Text']).encode('utf8').decode('utf8')

Anybody seen this? Is meltano broken?
I always get something along the lines of:
 "UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\\udc8f' in position 20: surrogates not allowed"

Why surrogates suddenly?
I really dont understand why this is such a nightmare? I am reading UTF8 and passing those strings around. Why is this happening?

I believe that MSSQL stores the data as UTF-16.  You may want to try decoding from that via record['Text'].decode('utf-16'), or you can force storage in UTF-8 using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS_UTF8

i cant really change the database unfortunately. The thing is that running only the mssql tap, it seems that the characters are correctly arriving. The console shows all of them. But as soon as they land at the target some problems occur. record['Text'].decode('utf-16') doesnt work, because its already a string and not bytes

Is the error occuring before or after the data is written as JSON?
